# Entity Intercept All Database Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In an existing Entity application, I need to call a remote API on every database change.

Im wondering if I can somehow hook into an event or class within entity to write my code. Something like the following Psuedo code

```
if (Table == "Business") Api.Call
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your `context.SaveChanges()` in a method call in your repository and process your changes there.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

//may be wrong syntax
public bool SaveAllChanges()
{
   var Changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified | e.State == EntityState.Added | e.State ...);
   foreach(var change in Changes)
   {
     //check if you need to call your API
   }

   return context.SaveChanges() > 0 
}
```